# Upload Image To Database Not Working

Tags: php, html, css, database, mysqli

I'm creating a form in html which will run php file and upload image and text in database.My html is directing perfectly to php but the uploading process not working.Everytime the submit button pressed,the php file show not working.

My Html Code :

```
<form name="f1" method="post" action="php/Savent.php" 
 enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <fieldset>
        <legend name = "addev" align="right"><b>Detail</b></legend>
        <table width="100%">
            <tr align="center">
                <th>Choose Image : </th>
                <td><input type="file" name="image"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><br/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="center">
                <th>Description : </th>
                <td><textarea name="desc" rows="6" cols="30" style="resize: 
                     none"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><br/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="center">
                <td colspan="2" align="center"><input name="submit" 
                  type="submit" value="Submit"/> <input type="reset" 
                  value="Reset"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><br/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Php Code :

```
 <?php

  if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    mysqli_connect("sql303.unaux.com","unaux_20153623","testin");
    mysqli_select_db("unaux_20153623_dummy");

    $imageName = mysqli_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    $imageData = 
    mysqli_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]
    ["tmp_name"]));
    $imageType = mysqli_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"]["type"]);
    $desc = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST["desc"]);

    if (substr($imageType,0,5) == "image"){
        echo "Working";
    mysqli_query("INSERT INTO 'events' 
    VALUES('','$imageName','$imageData','$desc')");
    echo "Saved Succesfully";
    }
    else{
    echo "Not Working";
    }
   }

   ?>
```

Comment: You're using the wrong enctype. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean

Comment: Also you need to pass your connection variable when executing the query.

Comment: Also in your insert statement,  you need to use backticks and not single quotes around your table name.  Make sure the events table has got only 4 columns

Answer (score 0):

add this  enctype="multipart/form-data" in form element you are using wrong enctype

Comment: That's only part of it. You missed a lot of stuff.

Comment: yes i saw code he has missed connection and his query has errors also and thanks for pointing out, because after your comment i saw his whole code but thankfully he has used mysqli not mysql